# Correct time Complexity

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have come across this question which asks to find the time complexity.

```
int count = 0;
        for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
```

It says that it's time complexity is `O(n)`, should it be `O(nlogn)` as the first loop is `logn` and second is `n`.

Comment: Your question was asked 1/2 days ago. You could look there as well.

Answer (score 1):

> It says that it`s time complexity is O(n), should it be O(nlogn) as
>   the first loop is logn and second is n.

The inner-loop is based on outer loop. So, your claim is not valid.

And, += (addition assignment operator) complexity is O(1).

For first iteration of the outer-loop, the inner-loop will execute for N times.

For second iteration of the outer-loop, the inner-loop will execute for N/2 times.

And, so on...

Therefore, total execution steps

```
       = N + N/2 + ... + 1
```

// log<sub>2</sub> N times Geometric Progression...

```
       ~ N / (1-(1/2)) (Infinite GP Summation Formula) //though the series would go up to 1
       ~ 2N.
       // ~ means approximately.
```

Therefore, the time complexity of the code comes out to be O(N).

So, the answer given is correct.

Comment: Lived up to your username in this case :)